# Why Aren't My Inserted Script Tags Visible?

Tags: javascript

I'm loading a block of script tags with a for loop from a js file.  That works as functions are called, but I don't understand why the script tags are not on the document in source view.

For example:

```
for (var str in library) {
    document.write("<script src='" + "scriptsfolder/" + "" + library[str] + "'></script>");
}
```

Where are those scripts written to? And why does this work?

The for loop is called after js file is loaded.

Comment: Because it doesn't exist in the DOM.

Comment: You're using `document.write`, think about it

Comment: To clarify the previous comments - most browsers, when using "View Source", make a _new_ request to the server to fetch the HTML for the page, and do not execute JavaScript. Use the browser's debugger/inspector (e.g. right click -> "Inspect Element" in Chrome) and you will see your new script tags.

Comment: I don't think this question is off topic, but it's not really answerable with a coding snippet or fix.

Comment: @Tom G, I thought for sure that every browser worked the same way. For this project I'm using Opera. Inspect -> element in Chrome & FF do show them. Thanks

Comment: Seems Opera gets the document from the filesystem not the browser itself when working locally

Comment: @TomG Seems like that would make a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most browsers, when using "View Source", make a *new* request to the server to fetch the HTML for the page, and do not execute JavaScript. Use the browser's debugger/inspector (e.g. right click -> "Inspect Element" in Chrome) and you will see your new script tags.